# QListWidget on mac os X show abnormal

Tags: macos, qt, qlistwidget

I use QListWidget on Qt Creator of mac, this is my code

```
m_pListWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("ttmanagevmlist"));
m_pListWidget->setFrameShape(QListWidget::NoFrame);
m_pListWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,false);
m_pListWidget->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
m_pListWidget->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
m_pListWidget->setResizeMode(QListView::Fixed);
m_pListWidget->setAutoScroll(true);
m_pListWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

But it shows abnormal,like this

[image]

It has blue border,but when it loses focus,it's normal. Who knows the reason of the problem?

Comment: Mind explaining what *abnormal* means in this context?

Comment: no,i mean it has a blue border,but this problem has been solved,the method is demonlus's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use this:

```
m_pListWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect, false);
```

Read about `Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect` [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

> Indicates that this widget should get a QFocusFrame around it. Some widgets draw their own focus halo regardless of this attribute. Not that the QWidget::focusPolicy also plays the main role in whether something is given focus or not, this only controls whether or not this gets the focus frame. This attribute is only applicable to OS X.